# Auto-Sync won't turn on

Tags: sync, 4.2-jelly-bean, google-account

Yesterday I bought [Videocon A27](http://www.fonearena.com/videocon-a27_2910.html) with Android 4.2.2

I'm not able to turn the auto-sync feature on. It is located under Settings -> Data Usage -> Menu -> Auto-sync data. When I check the option and reopen the menu, the option is unchecked. I also tried turning it on using Power Control Widget, but that too does not work.
Google account is already set up and I am able to sync data manually. I believe some sync service application is missing.

Does anyone have faced such issue earlier? Which Application is responsible for syncing data? (Google Calendar Sync and Google Contacts Sync are pre-installed on the device.)

Comment: This seems very likely to be a problem with the system integration by the device's manufacturer. You should try their official support channel. If they can fix it for you, please post the answer here to benefit future visitors.

Comment: The manufactures do not have any online forum or tech support. So that is not an option for me. I like the device (everything about the device is good except this problem) so I don't want to return the device either. Therefore I'm left with only one choice that is to fix it myself.